# how can i do multiple select with eloquent? (Laravel4)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'd like to ask a question about eloquent ORM on Laravel 4

---

**example*

**model name:** user

**table:** user

**column:** id, username, password, type

---

`User::find(1)` *this is retrieve the all of data

`User::find(1)->username;` * 1 data .

but how can I do multiple data?? like...

```
SELECT username, type FROM user where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply an array of fields like this:

```
User::where('id', '=', '1')->get(array('username', 'type'));
```

Comment: Awesome!! I did it with your way!!
Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$brazilianElders = User::where('country','Brazil')->where('age','>',60)->get();

foreach($brazilianElders as $user)
{
  echo "name: $user->name";
}
```

Comment: Thanks your response.but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent load all fields (*) for each model
so you can just call:
     $user->name
     $user->email

a query is executed only when model is created (the return of find)

Comment: Thanks your answer. I have to admit it.

Answer (score 0):

The Eloquent `find()` function will select all columns by default, which can be used like so:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->id;
echo $user->username;
echo $user->type;
```

If you wish to limit which columns are selected, simply pass an array of column names as the second argument:

```php
$user = User::find(1, array('id', 'type'));
echo $user->id;
echo $user->username; // Not set
echo $user->type;
```